# jackrabbit - How to track copied nodes

Tags: copy, jackrabbit

When copying a subtree (using Workspace.copy() )I want to keep a map of the copied node ID's and their corresponding new ID's.

I've come across the ItemStateListener but can't see how to get the info I want.

Andy ideas?

Cheers.